# Cache.Get always returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am experimenting with caching data and keep failing.  As you can see in the code below, I call upon a web service to return an array called 'categories'.  This call is successful and I get information back.  Right after populating the dropdown list with the results, I use an Insert to store the information to cache.  Upon page refresh (I guess I should say anything other than a postback), I check the cache to see if the information is there.  It never is.  Scratching my head on this one...

```
if (! IsPostBack)
{
    //See if the results have been cached.  With arrays and checking for null, you have to
    //check the array itself before its elements can be checked.
    string[] saveCatList = Cache.Get("Categories" + Session["sessionID"]) as string[];
    if (saveCatList == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(saveCatList[0]))
    {
        WBDEMOReference.getcatlist_itemcategories[] categories;
        strResult = callWebServ.getcatlist(Session["sessionID"].ToString(),
                    out strResultText, out dNumOfCat, out categories);

        for (int i = 0; i < categories.Length; i++)
        {
            //ddCat is the ID number of the category drop down list
            ddCat.Items.Add(new ListItem(categories[i].categorydesc.ToString(),
                                         categories[i].categorynumber.ToString()));
        }

        //Store the array into cache. 'Cache.Remove' will remove the cache for that key
        Cache.Insert("Categories" + Session["sessionID"], categories, null,
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug what Session["sessionID"] is? May be it's changing and altering the cache key by which you're looking up values in cache

Comment: I did, yes. The Session["sessionID"] is the same at Insert and Get time.

Comment: is it possible that `categories` isn't of type `string[]`? in that case, the `as` operator would cause it to become null

Comment: @sJhonny: The above code works and populates my drop down list? When I set up 'categories' in my watch window, I get 10 strings back (MEAT, DAIRY, PRODUCE, etc.).  Based on those results I use string[].

Comment: and what do you see when you watch `Cache.Get("Categories" + Session["sessionID"])`? or `Cache["Categories" + Session["sessionID"]]`?

Comment: @sJhonny:  Correction on the watch suggestion you had...I DO get a successful value on the Cache["Categories" + Session["sessionID"]].  It returns the expected value.  That being said, why won't it save to my string[] named saveCatList?  Very odd...

Comment: @sJhonny:  You were correct although I didn't realize it until MNGwinn stated it differently.  Turns out this service reference I imported into my project creates its own namespace and classes and I was too much of a rookie to get what you were saying.  Many thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think sJhonny got it in the comments. You put `categories` (an array of `WBDEMOReference.getcatlist_itemcategories`)in the cache, but do an `as string[]` when you take it back out. A mismatch of type with the as keyword will result in a null value. Try changing `as string[]` to `as WBDEMOReference.getcatlist_itemcategories[]` or add a check to see if it exists without using the `as string[]` cast.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I'm still learning how this imported service reference works - thanks for clearing that up :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using  HttpContext Cache which is not use in webcontext can be null so the suggestion would be to HttpRuntime Cache. The runtime cache will always be available in your application for e.g. even in a console app

Even the HttpContext use HttpRuntime Cache under the hood but in your scenario looks the runtime cache might do the job

I will be happy to delete my answer if some one corrected me the advise given is wrong

Comment: I tried modifying the code using 'HttpRuntime.Cache.Get' and 'HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert', however my results were the same.